# No APM data when updating webpage certificate

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apm

we have an operative webpage and an Elastic Stack collecting user data. This stack is composed of different docker containers, with Elasticsearch, Kibana, and one APM agent.

We have been successfully collecting user interaction data (GET requests, POST requests, etc.), but we are no longer able to receive this data since the webpage certificate was updated.

The certificate has been properly renewed, but APM data does not arrive from the previous certificate expiration date. The current configuration is somehow still using the old certificate.

We have already tried to reload/recreate stack containers, without success.

Does APM cache somehow the webpage certificate?
Is there any option to refresh APM configuration?